# write regex query in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a model named "SentEmail" and it has attribute named "email_type", some of them start with "email_verification" plus time stamp. For example, it could be like "email_verification_201413423". 
How could I query all the sent_email with attribute start with "email_verification"? How to write regex to query in rails?
This is the query I tried: SentEmail.where('person_id = 1277 AND email_type like "email_verification_%"')
but it has syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to do that with regex?

you can try this

```
SentEmail.where('email_type like "email_verification_%"')
```

but if you really need a regexp you could try

```
SentEmail.where('email_type REGEXP "email_verification*'")
```

I think that regex should be slower than sql like (obviously if you are working with activerecord and sql).

Comment: how can i add other parameters in it? like SentEmail.where('email_id = 12 AND email_type like "email_verification_%"') is this correct?

Comment: you can do this SentEmail.where('email_id = ? AND email_type like "email_verification_%", email_id')  That is a good practice if you want to put a variable

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SentEmail.where('email_type ~* :substring', :substring => "^email_verification")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
 SentEmail.where('email_type like ?', 'email_verification%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

And since you asked for Regex specifically:

```
SentEmail.where("email_type REGEXP ?", 'email_verification.*') #SQLITE with regexp installed?

SentEmail.where("email_type ~* ?", 'email_verification.*') #Postgresql
```

caveat: this is database dependent. Your DB may or may not support REGEXP and it may use a different syntax.